# How can i highlight a list card item on another view in ionic when navigating?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, css-animations

I have a list of unread "comments" in a menu - when i click i want to navigate to the comments group (a card item list), higlight and scroll to its `$index.`

I navigate to the group of cards like so:

```
ng-href="#/app/comments/{{comment.group}}#{{comment.id}}"
```

Using `$stateparams` I grab the group id `comment.group` and list all the comments listed like so:

```
<div class="list card fade" ng-repeat="comment in comments track by comment.id">


<div class="item item-avatar item-button-right item-stable">
    <img ng-if="!userInfo.image" src="img/icon.png">
    <img  ng-if="userInfo.image" ng-src="{{userInfo.image}}">
    <span ng-bind-html="userInfo.status"></span><span class="dark">{{userInfo.name}}</span>
    <p class="date">{{comment.date | date:'M/dd/yy'}}  {{comment.date | date:'h:mma'}}</p>
    <button class="button button-clear" ng-if='canDelete' ng-click='deleteComment()'>
        <i class="icon ion-ios-trash-outline"></i>
    </button>
</div>

<div id="{{comment.id}}" class="item item-text-wrap item-button-right">
    <span style="margin-left: 10px;">"{{comment.text}}"</span>
</div>
</div>
```

I set the `id` of the item text area to the `comment.id`

I'm trying to fade in all the cards and highlight `comment.id` item with the following css/scss:

```
.fade.ng-enter {
 /* standard transition code */
 transition: 1.0s linear all;
 opacity:0;
}
.fade.ng-enter-stagger {
  /* this will have a 100ms delay between each successive leave animation */
  transition-delay: 0.4s;


  transition-duration: 0s;
}
.fade.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  /* standard transition styles */
  opacity:1;
}

//Higlighting
:target{
  -webkit-animation: target-fade 3s 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes target-fade {
  0% {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.1) !important;
  }
  100%{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
  }
}
```

both the `fade` and `target-fade` animations aren't working.

I do not know how to scroll to the index of the card in ionic - I was hoping the `#` tag would act as an anchor and work its magic...

can anyone help with this?

Comment: You should use ng-class, for dynamic selector.

Comment: @AtaurRahimChowdhury can you elaborate. can i check for `:target`?